# PHP Highest value from array and save keys

Tags: php

I have array

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
        [message_id] => 1,
        [points] => 3,
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [message_id] => 2,
        [points] => 2,
    )
    [3] => Array(
        [message_id] => 3,
        [points] => 2,
    )
)
```

and i need to get `message_id` value from array where points is most highest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop in your array and check the points to find the highest one

```
$points = 0;
foreach($array as $val) {
    if($val['points'] > $points) {
        $points = $val['points'];
        $message_id = $val['message_id'];
    }
}

echo $message_id;
//prints 1
```

[**Live sample**](http://ideone.com/CS0QSt)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$array = array(
    1 => array(
        'message_id' => 1,
        'points' => 3,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'message_id' => 2,
        'points' => 2,
    ),
    3 => array(
        'message_id' => 3,
        'points' => 2,
    ),
);

$highest = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
    if($arr['message_id'] > $highest) {
        $highest = $arr['message_id'];
    }
}

echo "Highest: " . $highest;
```

The output for the `$highest` number would be: 3.

[See working example](https://3v4l.org/or0FO).